# Linux How to execute a command when a certain type of file is modified?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to execute "lessc ~/less/app.less > ~/stylesheets/styles.css" everytime I modify a .less file on my machine. Is it possible ?

Comment: `lessc` already does this for you.  See `--watch`.

Comment: Seems like my question is off-topic. I'm sorry, I did not read the whole help center, next time I will ask on Super User so I wont lose 25% of my reputation points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a generic approach, Linux kernel has a feature called `inotify` that monitors file system changes.

You will have to write a small program to make use of the interface. inotify has bindings for all major languages, including perl and python .

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [incron](http://linuxaria.com/article/incron-cron-inotify?lang=en), a crontab-like system for inotify. You can set up rules to trigger any commands you want, based on events in the filesystem.